# Google script editor send email on value insert or change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-apps-script-editor

I would like to make my sheets to send email message once one field is updated/inserted.

Was trying to follow a few guides, but unfortunately, not getting the result I want

Lets say I have this document:

[image]

The most important column is "I" - if the value is inserted here (date) - email must be sent to the client. Client's email can be found in "E" column.

So, what I have to do is to take email from "E" and send him the email with correct date from "I" field.

[image]

In this scenario: I have to send the email to user "a@a.com" with the date "2020-01-16"

These rows can be inserted any time since it's connected with Google forms, so the script should always look up if there are any new rows.

Comment: In your situation, the row is appended with the Google Form, and you have already prepared the script you expect. If my understanding is correct, how about using the OnSubmit event trigger as the installable trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) By this, when the Google Form is submitted, the script can be run by the trigger. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an installable trigger, it might be **on form submit** or **on change**

The first will be run every time a new form submission is done. The second will be triggered every time a change (edit, insert row, remove row, etc) is done. Please bear in mind that each trigger has its own event object.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable